# Не отображается cell из grid layout group

Tags: unity3d

Пробовал менять order in layer, менял позицию по Z.
Если вывести gameObject - Alyminiym отдельно то объект отображается.
Ошибка возможно может быть банальной, но я не знаю что делать.
Помогите пожалуйста кто знает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашел некую проблему в отображении самой картинки. Она очень сильно уменьшена что её в принципе вообще не видно визуально.
Но если сильно приблизить объект, то её видно. Может кто то знает что с отображением?

Comment: Вся проблема была в неправильно установленных размерах.